# Remove white space in flexbox container

Tags: html, css, flexbox, padding

So I'm trying to code my site for neocities, this is my first time using flexboxes. But in my first flexbox, the inside of this box had no padding until i added it. The rest of the boxes seem to start as if they had a top padding to it.

```css
.flexContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-left: 60px;
  width: 1100px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.leftContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 247px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.about {
  width: 247px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-image: url(brd2.png) 30 round;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url("https://foollovers.com/mat/heart02/n01-bg-heart.gif");
}

.about p {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.abImg img {
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.def {
  width: 247px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-image: url(brd2.png) 30 round;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url("https://foollovers.com/mat/heart02/n01-bg-heart.gif");
}

.vwx {
  width: 247px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-image: url(brd2.png) 30 round;
  height: 180px;
  background-image: url("https://foollovers.com/mat/heart02/n01-bg-heart.gif");
  padding: 0px;
}

.vwImg {
  width: 247px;
  height: 180px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexContainer">
  <div class="leftContainer">
    <div class="about">
      <div class="abImg">
        <img src="about.png">
      </div>
      <p>N30N/LUNA</p>

      <p>27|they/them|Cancer</p>

      <p><img src="https://foollovers.com/mat/i-s-hw/df05-halloween-cat.gif">My About<img src="https://foollovers.com/mat/i-s-hw/df05-halloween-cat.gif"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="def">
      <p>2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="vwx">
      <div class="vwImg">
        <p><img src="img1.png"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

here's what it looks like:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzPMM.png)

I've tried putting padding: 0px, and margin 0px, and it doesn't change it. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

What you're thinking is extra padding is actually paragraph margins. `<p>` elements have a default top and bottom margin. You can style that away if you wish.

In this snippet, the left column is styled with the default paragraph margins, whereas the right column has had those margins removed.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  gap: 2em;
  align-items: start;
}

.d1, .d2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 250px;
  text-align: center;
  gap: 10px;
  background-image: url("https://foollovers.com/mat/heart02/n01-bg-heart.gif");
}

.d1>*, .d2>* {
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.d2 p {
  margin: 0;
}

.d2 .block-image {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
  <div class="about">
    <img class="block-image" src="http://picsum.photos/120">
    <p>N30N/LUNA</p>
    <p>27|they/them|Cancer</p>
    <p>
      <img src="https://foollovers.com/mat/i-s-hw/df05-halloween-cat.gif">
      My About
      <img src="https://foollovers.com/mat/i-s-hw/df05-halloween-cat.gif">
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="def">
    <p>2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="vwx">
    <p><img class="block-image" src="http://picsum.photos/100"></p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="d2">
  <div class="about">
    <img class="block-image" src="http://picsum.photos/120">
    <p>N30N/LUNA</p>
    <p>27|they/them|Cancer</p>
    <p>
      <img src="https://foollovers.com/mat/i-s-hw/df05-halloween-cat.gif">
      My About
      <img src="https://foollovers.com/mat/i-s-hw/df05-halloween-cat.gif">
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="def">
    <p>2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="vwx">
    <p><img class="block-image" src="http://picsum.photos/100"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This fixed it!! Thank you so much!! I was pulling my hair out over this.